# Something I can't understand in Acquia Marina theme

Tags: 7, theming

I have downloaded the Acquia Marina theme yesterday.

I cannot understand well the following code; there is a lot of code like the following, in [page.tpl.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/acquia_marina.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/page.tpl.php).

```
<?php print theme('grid_block', $search_box, 'search-box'); ?>
<?php print theme('grid_block', theme('links', $secondary_links), 'secondary-menu'); ?>
<?php print theme('grid_block', $primary_links_tree, 'primary-menu'); ?>
<?php print theme('grid_block', $tabs, 'content-tabs'); ?>
<?php print theme('grid_block', $footer_message, 'footer-message-text'); ?>
..............
```

Acquia Marina theme version is 6.x-3.1. I didn't find a template.php file between its files. Where is the variable declared? Why doesn't the code use `$primary_links_tree` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Acquia Marina theme is a sub-theme of Fusion core. `$primary_links_tree` is defined in the template file of that theme, in the [fusion_core_preprocess_page()](http://drupalcode.org/project/fusion.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/fusion_core/template.php#l28), which the preprocess function that is called before page.tpl.php is used to output a page. Starting from [line 80](http://drupalcode.org/project/fusion.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/fusion_core/template.php#l80), you find the following code:

```
$vars['primary_links_tree'] = '';
if ($vars['primary_links']) {
  if (theme_get_setting('primary_menu_dropdown') == 1) {
    // Check for menu internationalization
    if (module_exists('i18nmenu')) {
      $vars['primary_links_tree'] = i18nmenu_translated_tree(variable_get('menu_primary_links_source', 'primary-links'));
    }
    else {
      $vars['primary_links_tree'] = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_primary_links_source', 'primary-links'));
    }
    $vars['primary_links_tree'] = preg_replace('/<ul class="menu/i', '<ul class="menu sf-menu', $vars['primary_links_tree'], 1);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: got it. thank you.<?php print theme('grid_block', theme('links', $secondary_links), 'secondary-menu'); ?> what's this line meaning. there are two theme() function in it.namely,when print it. the theme will look for the theme_grid_block() function and theme_links function. am i right?

Comment: @enjoylife Yes, you are; those are the theme functions that are invoked, if there are no modules that override them.